# Google play console to bigquery migration

Tags: google-bigquery, google-play-console

I know there is a monthly charge of $25 per unique Package Name for automating Google Play Console to BigQuery migration.

My question is what does "unique Package name" mean? One app equals a unique package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the **Google Play Console to BigQuery migration service**, a `"unique Package Name"` corresponds to the **specific Android application package name** linked to an app available on the Google Play Store. If you have multiple apps published on the Google Play Store, each app will have its unique package name. Consequently, if you aim to automate the data migration from the Google Play Console to BigQuery for multiple apps, you will incur a charge of $25 per unique package name on a monthly basis.

Note: Each individual package name, the charge will amount to $25 per month. It's essential to note that the billing is determined by the number of distinct package names used, and not based on the number of individual data points or records being transferred during the migration process.